# Infinite sets having no RE subsets

Tags: logic, computability

I'm back trying to learn recursion theory on my own. I'd like to prove the following result: There exists an infinite set having no infinite R.E. subset.
Constructive comments are appreciated.

**Proof**: To show the claim, we proceed by reductio. Suppose every infinite set has infinite R.E. subsets. WOLOG, let $Z$ = {$Z_0$, $Z_1$, . . .} be a countable collection of infinite sets. By hypothesis, for every $Z_i$ $\in$ $Z$ there is a  ***$W_j$*** such that ***$W_j$*** $\subset$ $Z_i$, where j is the index of an R.E. set. Hence we can form a collection say $W$ = {***$W_0$***, ***$W_1$***, . . .} of these R.E. sets. Note that every R.E. subset for the collection $Z$ is represented in $W$. We also note that R.E. sets are closed under arbitrary unions. Hence, we can take $\bigcup$$W$, which must be an R.E. set, and so is the R.E. subset for some member of $Z$. But all of these subsets were represented in $W$, since $W$ was assumed exhaustive. This latter fact contradicts our assumption that $W$ was exhaustive, so that there must be an infinite set with no R.E. subset after all.

Comment: It's certainly not true that R.E. sets are closed under arbitrary unions. Every singleton is an R.E. sets, and if this claim would be correct then every set would be R.E.

Comment: Thanks so much Asaf. Any suggestions for what the proof should look like?

Comment: Nothing off the top of my head, and I'm a bit too exhausted to think about it at this hour (or I'd have posted a proper answer, of course). It should be some sort of diagonalization, I think. Just a careful one.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll keep thinking about it and give it a shot later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any fixed $S=\{s_1, s_2, \ldots \}$, the probability that all the $s_i$'s are in a random set is $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \cdots =0$. Since probability is countably sub-additive, the probability that one of any fixed countable collection is a subset of a random set is 0. Thus most sets have no infinite c.e. subset.

Comment: Now *that* is a very interesting proof! Thanks so much for that, Quinn.

Comment: I'm confused how the probability that a specific infinite set is a subset of a random infinite set being zero implies anything about the probability of any c.e. set being a subset of a random set.

Comment: It's basically the same as why the rationals has probability zero; because each of its countably many elements has probability zero.

Answer (score 4):

You have an enumeration of the infinite r.e. sets. Let $m_0$ and $n_0$ be the two smallest elements of the first set, $m_1$ and $n_1$ the smallest elements of the second set different from $m_0$ and $n_0$, and so on. Then $\{m_k:k\in\omega\}$ does not contain any infinite r.e. set.

**Added:** Such sets are called *immune*. And as bof notes in the comments, the construction above has nothing to do with recursive enumerability; it’s just a handy way to construct an infinite set that doesn’t contain any member of a specified (sufficiently small) family of infinite sets.

Comment: Of course this has nothing to do with recursion theory, just the fact that the collection of all (infinite) r.e. sets is countable. A more interesting exercise: construct an **r.e.** set whose complement in infinite but contains no infinite r.e. set. (If I remember right such an r.e. set is called a **simple** set.)

Comment: There are many natural examples, too. For example, the set of minimal programs (that is, the set of $e$ such that $e$ is the minimal $j$ with $\varphi_j=f$ for some p.r. $f$) is immune.

Comment: Thanks so much Brian, et al. Just so I can be clear, Brian's construction does not look to me like a diagonalization. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: @لويسالعرب: It’s a sort of diagonalization: it ‘takes care of’ the r.e. sets one at a time, handling each one with a different part of the set being constructed.

Comment: Ok, I think I see it now. It's just different from any diagonalization I've seen!

Comment: is there any way to guarantee that these inmune sets are co-infinite?